# Is HttpCookie.Name the same as the string in Response.Cookies[string]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Meaning I create a cookie with .Name = "ChocolateChip" then later I would look for it by being like: Response.Cookies["ChocolateChip"]... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the same name.  (I checked the source)